# Limit logfile size in Python logging

Tags: python, logging

Limiting the log file size in python, as far as I can tell, can be done with the `RotatingFileHandler` and it's attribute `maxBytes`.

To test this, I wrote the following script:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# add a rotating handler
handler = RotatingFileHandler("test.log", maxBytes=1)
logger.addHandler(handler)

x = 0
while True:
    x += 1
    logger.info(x)
```

Even though the logfile should not exceed 1 byte, it goes up until many megabytes pretty quickly. How can I limit this? Sadly the documentation is pretty bad. I also wanted to know how to make sure that every time I rerun the python script, the log file is cleared and started fresh, however, in the docu it just says

```
class logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename, mode='a', maxBytes=0, backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=False)

If mode is not specified, 'a' is used.
```

However, it does not say what other options instead of 'a' there are.

To sum up the questions

1. How can I limit the log file size to, let's say 10 megabytes
2. How can I ensure a fresh logfile is started if the script is run, and not an old one appended

Edit: I tried it with maxBytes=1000000, but the result remained the same. The logfile just keeps getting bigger

Comment: I wouldn't expect `maxBytes=1` to *ever* work. Logging is line-based, not character-based. That might simply be an invalid setting, since just about any log message is *already* going to exceed the max. size. Do you get the same behavior if you set a more reasonable `maxBytes` value?

Comment: I just tried it with maxBytes=1000000 (1 megabyte) and increased the size of the string to speed it up a little. It went up to 1.1 GB before I interrupted. The

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the 2nd section of [RotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler) class

> Rollover occurs whenever the current log file is nearly maxBytes in length; **but if either of maxBytes or backupCount is zero, rollover never occurs**, so **you generally want to set backupCount to at least 1, and have a non-zero maxBytes.**

It looks like you didn't setup the `backupCount` value.

> When backupCount is non-zero, **the system will save old log files by appending the extensions ‘.1’, ‘.2’ etc., to the filename.**

> For example, with a backupCount of 5 and a base file name of app.log, you would get app.log, app.log.1, app.log.2, up to app.log.5. The file being written to is always app.log.

> When this file is filled, it is closed and renamed to app.log.1, and if files app.log.1, app.log.2, etc. exist, then they are renamed to app.log.2, app.log.3 etc. respectively.